# How to resolve ZFS userspace tools and kernel module mismatch caused by HWE automatic updates

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, kernel, zfs

I am on Ubuntu LTS 20.04 with kernel version 5.15.0-91-generic. I find that my ZFS user utils are version 0.8.3 and my ZFS kernel module is 2.1.5. As I understand it, not only is it risky having the userspace tools and kernel module be mismatched, but 2.1.5 is also at risk of the [recent silent corruption bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/2044657).

I assume how I got here is that Ubuntu LTS 20.04 comes with ZFS 0.8.3 for both user tools and kernel module, but due to another [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/zfs-linux/+bug/1939210), automatic HWE updates ended up updating the ZFS kernel module without the userspace tools.

What is the best way to go about fixing the mismatch and getting off the version impacted by silent corruption? I’d like to be as surgical as possible about this with minimal impact to the rest of the system. Easiest way I can think of is downgrading my kernel back to the original version, but I’m guessing downgrading ZFS kernel module (and others) is possibly unsafe? Alternatively, should I just build everything from source? How would I switch from the built-in kernel module to the one I built? Any other better options?

Comment: Did you upgrade your pool to the new feature flags included in 2.1.5? If no, then you should be able to still run your pool on 0.8.3.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure about the best approach when you currently have a newer kernel module than ZFS utils... 